# Automating the "sudo su - user" command 

Tags: linux, sudo, su

I want to automate

```
sudo su - user
```

from a script. It should then ask for a password.

Comment: Don't `sudo su - user`, use `sudo -iu user` instead. (Easier to manage through `sudoers`, by the way.)

Comment: How are you able to run `sudo su` without being able to run `sudo visudo`?

Answer (score 9):

I will try and guess what you asked.

If you want to use `sudo su - user` without a password, you should (if you have the privileges) do the following on you sudoers file:

```
<youuser>  ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - <otheruser>
```

where:

- `<yourusername>` is you username :D (saumun89, i.e.)
- `<otheruser>` is the user you want to change to

Then put into the script:

```
sudo /bin/su - <otheruser>
```

Doing just this, won't get subsequent commands get run by `<otheruser>`, it will spawn a new shell. If you want to run another command from within the script as this other user, you should use something like:

```
 sudo -u <otheruser> <command>
```

And in sudoers file:

```
<yourusername>  ALL = (<otheruser>) NOPASSWD: <command>
```

Obviously, a more generic line like:

```
<yourusername> ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Will get things done, but would grant the permission to do anything as anyone.

Comment: when the sudo su - user command gets executed,it asks for a password. i want a solution in which script automaticaaly reads password from somewhere. i dont have permission to do what u told earlier.

Comment: i have the permission to store password in a file. the script should read password from that file

Answer (score 4):

You can use command

```
 echo "your_password" | sudo -S [rest of your parameters for sudo]
```

(Of course without [ and ])

Please note that you should protect your script from read access from unauthorized users. If you want to read password from separate file, you can use

```
  sudo -S [rest of your parameters for sudo] < /etc/sudo_password_file
```

(Or whatever is the name of password file, containing password and single line break.)

From sudo man page:

```
   -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
               the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The
               password must be followed by a newline character.
```

Comment: This actually works for me.

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make it so that user doesn't have to type a password at all.

You can do that by running `visudo`, then changing the line that looks like:

```
someuser  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
someuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However if it's just for one script, it would be more secure to restrict passwordless access to only that script, and remove the `(ALL)`, so they can only run it as root, not any user , e.g.

```
Cmnd_Alias THESCRIPT = /usr/local/bin/scriptname

someuser  ALL=NOPASSWD: THESCRIPT
```

Run `man 5 sudoers` to see all the details in the [sudoers man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html).

Comment: i do not have permission to edit sudoers file.. any other so that it should read password from somewhere so that automation of this can be done.

Comment: you are out of luck ... you could do this with, lets say `expect` but that would let the password for your user hardcoded somewhere, where people could see it (granted that you setup permissions the right way, it could still be read by root).

Comment: Try using `expect`.  `man expect` for details.

Comment: when the sudo su - user command gets executed,it asks for a password. i want a solution in which script automaticaaly reads password from somewhere. i dont have permission to edit sudoers file.i have the permission to store password in a file.the script should read password from that file

Answer (score 1):

When you login into a shell session via putty or moba where you have stored the login credentials for a non root account, simply add this command to be executed upon login in by putty or moba and it will switch your access to root right away.

`echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S su - && sudo su`

Comment: Welcome on the site! Please explain, how does it work.

Comment: When you login into a shell session via putty or moba where you have stored the login credentials for a non root account, simply add this command to be executed upon login in by putty or moba and it will switch your access to root right away.

Comment: Not in a comment, insert it into your answers. Comments are "secondary citizens", they are only for clarifications and so. The answer has to be a round thing, comprehensible even if all the comments are deleted.

Comment: Sorry - thx for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use python pudo package: https://pypi.org/project/pudo/1.0.0/

Installation:

```
user$ sudo -H pip3 install pudo # you can install using pip2 also
```

Below is the code snippit for using in python automation for running cmds under root privilege::

```
user$ python3 # or python2
>>> import pudo
>>> (ret, out) = pudo.run(('ls', '/root')) # or pudo.run('ls /root')
>>> print(ret)
>>> 0
>>> print(out)
>>> b'Desktop\nDownloads\nPictures\nMusic\n'
```

Below is the cmd example for running cmds under root privilege

```
user$ pudo ls /root
Desktop  Downloads  Pictures  Music
```