# automate sudo su - user command without using expect or editing sudoers file

Tags: unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automate sudo su - user command](https://superuser.com/questions/243499/automate-sudo-su-user-command)

when the sudo su - user command gets executed inj script ,it asks for a password. i want a solution in which script automaticaaly reads password from somewhere. i dont have permission to edit sudoers file.i have the permission to store password in a file.the script should read password from that file . also expect is not installed and i do not have permission to install it on machine from where the script would be run

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions; if you need to you can use the **edit** function at the bottom of the question you have already asked to add further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command

```
 echo "your_password" | sudo -S <rest of your parameters for sudo>
```

(Of course without < and >)

Please note that you should protect your script from read access from unauthorized users. If you want to read password from separate file, you can use

```
 cat /etc/sudo_password_file | sudo -S <rest of your parameters for sudo>
```

(Or whatever is the name of password file, containing password and single line break.)

From sudo man page:

```
   -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
               the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The
               password must be followed by a newline character.
```